# "Fails to install drivers" error with a BCM 4312

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Broadcom BCM 43XX Wireless card working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-get-broadcom-bcm-43xx-wireless-card-working)

I am using a Dell Inspiron 1464. My wlan card is a Dell wireless 1397 whose chipset is made by Broadcom. The chip is bcm 4312.

In Ubuntu 11.04 my wlan card is detected and proprietary drivers have installed successfully.  Everything seems to be working fine.

The problem is in Ubuntu 11.10. It detects my wlan card, but when I press activate it says "failed to install drivers'.

What could cause this error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try to reinstall the drivers,

remove drivers:

```
sudo aptitude remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

install:

```
sudo aptitude install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

restart your computer and see if wifi workd or not.

Comment: It worked for me
DELL 1535, Ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 0):

or just use synaptic package manager to reinstal the `bcmwl-kernel-source`.